# MongoDB C# - how to save arbitrary JSON document as dynamic type?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to write a general purpose Web Api controller that will allow me to save a JSON document to a collection WITHOUT specifying a C# type. I've tried to condense the code down to the essentials:

```
public class PassThroughController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/mongodb/{collection}")]
    public void Post(string collection, dynamic document)
    {
        const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("SampleDb");
        var mongoCollection = db.GetCollection(collection);

        mongoCollection.Save(document,
            new MongoInsertOptions
            {
                WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged
            });
        }
}
```

I'm trying to post a simple document:

```
{ id: "2112", name: "Rush" }
```

But no matter what I send to the method, I get an error similar to this: "Save can only be used with documents that have an Id."

We've attempted a number of different properties for Id (Id, id, _id) but they all result in a similar issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With the help of a co-worker, I figured out a solution:

```cs
public class PassThroughController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/mongodb/{collection}")]
    public void Post(string collection, HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        const string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("SampleDb");
        var mongoCollection = db.GetCollection(collection);

        var json = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);

        mongoCollection.Save(document,
            new MongoInsertOptions
            {
                WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to save some dynamic object associated to a ProcessID, the dynamic object it's totally "dynamic", sometimes it can be one property with some arbitrary data and name, sometimes it can be a 100 properties with totally arbitrary names for each property. In fact, it's an object coming from an Angular 5 app that generates a dynamic form from (surprise) some JSON object. My "base" class, the one that get inserted into mongo it's like this:

```
public class MongoSave {

    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    public string Id { get; set; }        
    public int ProcessID { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument DynamicData { get; set; }

}
```

On my first attempt the `DynamicData` property was type `object`, the controller method received everything ok, assign the incoming object to the class but when saving the object to mongo the values for `DynamicData` were lost. I was getting only the property names. Tried to use the `BsonSerialize`annotation in my class but with no success.

Researching a little bit i discovered that `BsonDocument` has a `Parse` method similar to javascript that parse a string containing an object description, so... i posted an object like this to my controller:

```
{
    "ProcessID": 987,
    "DynamicData": {
        "name": "Daniel",
        "lastName": "Díaz",
        "employeeID": 654
    }
{
```

A few things here, i'm sending via Insomnia (a Postman alternative) this JSON to the API. In real world i'll be sending this object via Angular so i have to be sure to apply `JSON.stringify(obj)` to be sure that the JSON object it's ok (don't know for sure if the Angular `HttpClient` post objects as stringified JSON or as JS objects (i'll test that). Changed my controller action to use the `Parse` method and the `DynamicData` C# generic `object` to string like this:

```
[HttpPost("~/api/mongotest/save")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostObjectToMongo (MongoSaveDTO document) {

    MongoSave mongoItem = new MongoSave() {
        ProcessID = document.ProcessID,
        DynamicData = BsonDocument.Parse(document.DynamicData.ToString())
    };

    await _mongoRepo.AddMongoSave(mongoItem);

    return Ok();
}
```

The `MongoSaveDTO` it's the same as `MongoSave` without the `BsonId`property and instead of `BsonDocument` i'm using C# generic `object` type and everything saves like a charm.

Comment: That is very interesting. Thank you for sharing. I tried using ExandoObject and had all sorts of hell with serialistion.. but I like you can just use the object like `obj.DynamicVar = "test"` as that makes assigning values easier. But saving it to Mongo didnt go well :( May try your solution

Answer (score 0):

It is the easiest to register custom json serializer:

```
public class BsonDocumentJsonConverter : JsonConverter<BsonDocument>
{
    public override BsonDocument Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        BsonDocument.Parse(reader.GetString());

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        BsonDocument value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}
```

after use it in entity:

```
public class ContentEntity: EntityBase
{
    public string Repository { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string ContentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BsonDocumentJsonConverter))]
    public BsonDocument Content { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BsonDocumentJsonConverter))]
    public BsonDocument Meta { get; set; }
}
```