# Convert c# space delimited string into MongoDB BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb

I succeeded in uploading a BSONdocument to my cloud MongoDB database using for example:

```cs
var temp = new BsonDocument
{
    {"timestamp", now},
    {"room1",20},
    {"room2",24},
    {"room3",14}
};
```

However, this was only a test, my real application is getting a space delimited string which I still need to convert to such a BsonDocument. How can I do that? The string to convert would look like this :

```cs
string data = "pm 49.8 42.4 2.2 52.1 51.6 50.8 10.3 120.0 120.0 20.0 20.0 120.0 0.0 0.0 20.0 20.0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0 1 0.0 53.7 0.0 0.0 80.0 46.4 27.7 20.0 22.5 57.0 51.0 27.0 26.0 19.5 -20.0 -20.0 20.0 20.0 -20.0 0.0 0.0 20.0 20.0 0 28.8 48.2 57 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 121.0 61.0 10.4 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 -20.0 0.0 20.0 20.0 -20.0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 20.0 20.0 20.0 20.0 22.5 20.0 20.0 -20.0 1 15.9 0.0 0 0 2 -20 61 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 1 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 51 51 0000 0003 0000 0003 2000 0000 0000 0000"
```

The left side of the BsonDocument (room1, room2,… In the example above) items may become for example ID0, ID1, ID2, ...
Thanks!

The schema for the object i want to create may look like this:

```cs
var whatineed= new BsonDocument
{
    {"timestamp", now},
    {"id0",49.8},
    {"id1",42.4},
    {"id2",2.2}
    ...and so on
};
```

Comment: How is the schema for the object do you want to create?

Comment: Schema added for the object that i want to create.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion. I tried something similar as my Linq knowledge is too little, but it works :-)

```
Console.WriteLine("Trying to send now...");
timestamp = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(timestamp);
string data = "{'timestamp':'" + timestamp + "'";
string[] split = read.Split(' ');
if (split.Length > 137)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < (split.Length-2); i++)
   {
       data += ", 'id" + i.ToString() + "':'" + split[i+1] + "'";
   }
   data += "}";                            
   var document = new BsonDocument();
   document.AddRange(BsonDocument.Parse(data));
   send(document);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536306/mongodb-c-sharp-how-to-save-arbitrary-json-document-as-dynamic-type) you can pass a json string and `BsonDocument` will do the magic.

So, try this line (I've not used much `String.Aggregate()` so maybe exists a better solution)

```cs
string json = "{{\"timestamp\":"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+"},{\"id0\":" +
                 data.Split(" ").Skip(1).Aggregate((pp, w) => $"{pp}}}, {{\"id{i++}\":{w}").TrimEnd(',') +"}}";
```

As I've said I'm not keen on into `String.Aggregate()` so I've splited by space, skip the first value and agregate adding the `{ }` and ids.

This will create a json with the schema you need, and then...

```cs
var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
mongoCollection.Save(document ... ) //whatever you need
```